# Email templates as scala templates in Play?

Tags: playframework-2.0

In Play 1.2.4. you could send complex, dynamic e-mail using the standard templates mechanism and syntax ([link](http://www.playframework.org/documentation/1.2.4/emails)), this looks realy cooll although I haven't used it. Is the [mailer plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/play-plugins/tree/master/mailer) of Play2.0 capable of such things?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

If by "complex, dynamic e-mail" you mean HTML email body based on template, you can do the same with Play 2.0.

You just have to create a new view based on a template, for instance `mailBody.scala.html`:

```
@(user:User)

<h3>Welcome @user.name</h3>
<br/>
....
```

Then, in your method which sends an email, you just have to call the `render()` method of your view:

```
public static void sendMail(User user) {

   MailerAPI mail = play.Play.application().plugin(MailerPlugin.class).email();
   mail.setSubject(...);
   mail.addRecipient(user.email);
   mail.addFrom(...);

   String body = views.html.mailBody.render(user).body();
   mail.sendHtml(body);

}
```

Comment: Haha, I just found this out, man I love this framework! Just one extra question: what would be the difference between <view>.toString() and your suggestion: <view>.body()??

Comment: From the source code, it is the same: https://github.com/playframework/Play20/blob/master/framework/src/play/src/main/scala/play/api/templates/Templates.scala#L28