# load a html page as the mail body

Tags: java, playframework

When developing with the Play Framework 2.0(Java version), I have a question as that I want to send email with a html,
e.g.

```
/app
```

`--a.html`

`--controller`

how can I  load the a.html as the mail body?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12538368/email-templates-as-scala-templates-in-play

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this example:

```
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.Authenticator;
import javax.mail.BodyPart;
import javax.mail.Message;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Multipart;
import javax.mail.PasswordAuthentication;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.Transport;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMultipart;
import javax.mail.internet.AddressException;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeBodyPart;

...

// set up smtp
Properties props = System.getProperties();
props.put("mail.transport.protocol", "smtp");
// if needed
props.put("mail.smtp.auth", "true");
props.put("mail.smtp.ssl.enable", SMTP_SSL_ENABLE);
props.put("mail.smtp.host", SMTP_SERVER);
props.put("mail.smtp.port", SMTP_PORT);
props.put("mail.user", SMTP_USER);
props.put("mail.password", SMTP_PASSWD);

Authenticator = new Authenticator() {
    public PasswordAuthentication getPasswordAuthentication() {
        return new PasswordAuthentication(SMTP_USER, SMTP_PASSWD);
    }
};

// create message
Session session = Session.getDefaultInstance(props, authenticator);
Message message = new MimeMessage(session);
message.setFrom(new InternetAddress(SMTP_SENDER));
message.addRecipient(Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(email));
message.setSubject("emails title");
BodyPart messageBodyPart = new MimeBodyPart();
messageBodyPart.setContent(yourTemplate.render().body(), "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
Multipart multipart = new MimeMultipart();
multipart.addBodyPart(messageBodyPart);
message.setContent(multipart);
message.saveChanges();

// send message
Transport.send(message);
```

You should replace the *play view template body part* with your html document:

```
messageBodyPart.setContent(yourTemplate.render().body(), "text/html; charset=iso-8859-1");
```

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

```
/Controller/Mails.java  method: sendmail()
public static void sendmail(){
    send(body)
}
/Views/Mails/sendmail.html [template]
```